# Java: Ask for continue

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator, restart

I'm trying to make a calculator. These operators: `x`, `+`, `-`, `/` work fine.

But I want the user to be able to do 2 things after he gets the answer on his math problem.

Ask user if he wants to continue.

1. If user types in `yes` he gets to put in 2 numbers that it counts again.
2. If the user types `no` just shut down.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Minscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nr1 = Integer.parseInt(Minscanner.nextLine());
        int nr2 = Integer.parseInt(Minscanner.nextLine());
        int yes = Integer.parseInt(Minscanner.nextLine());//trying to fix reset
        int ans =0;
        int reset = J;/trying to make it reset if user types in yes
        String anvin = Minscanner.nextLine();

        if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
            ans = nr1 + nr2;
        }
        else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
            ans = nr1 - nr2;
        }
        else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            ans = nr1 * nr2;
        }
        else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
            ans = nr1 / nr2;
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
        if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a

```
do {
    ...
} while (condition);
```

loop, and in your case the condition would be something like `wantToContinue` if user say "yes".

Then the program will not end unless user no longer wants to calculate.

Comment: thanks for the answere , but how would it look after i put my code in a do{ ..} condition;?

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code as bellow. This may help you

```
    boolean status=true;
    while (status){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your two numbers one by one :\n");
    int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
    int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your operation you want to perform ? ");
    int ans =0;
    String option = scanner1.nextLine();
    if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
        ans = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
        ans = num1 - num2;
    }
    else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
        ans = num1 * num2;
    }
    else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
        ans = num1 / num2;
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
     System.out.println("you want to try again press y press j for shutdown\n");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input=sc.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("J")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            status = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey , ive tried that code , well problem is then that it stops after i enter 2 numbers doesnt let me + - / * or choose j , and i want it to first ask for for a calculation , when it calculated out what user input it should ask if user wanna do it again or shutdown

Comment: @user2764700 ok. you can try now. is that you want?

Comment: yes thats what i was looking for ruchira time to read the code 100 times understand it and recreate it thanks aLOOT for the help took me 6 hours to get the calc working and now this fixed the other issue fast <33

Comment: if its not to ask could u just explain

this  "boolean status=true;
    while (status){
" ?

Comment: if its not much to ask for ** could u explain the boolean status true while status thing?

Comment: This while loop continue until status=false. If user want to continue calculation we have to keep status=true